# Broken Pipe Error in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, celery, broken-pipe

I setup and use Redis cache and Django celery in my Django app. Everything was working normal for two days, but I tried to change one my template page while server is on today. When I refresh the page, it doesn't recognize the change and I get this line on terminal:

- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50629)
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50634)

I tried to restart my server connection couple times, but it doesn't work. I am not sure what can be the reason, I want share settings code which is related with cache and celery.

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
    # 'LOCATION': '/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid',
    # 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:6379',

            }
         }

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = "default"
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''


# Celery Task
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False
```

I changed to Redis from Memcached, but it was also working okay just yesterday. Any suggestion for the solution would be great, because it really affects behaviour of application. I can share more codes if you want.

Thanks,

Comment: what exactly is the problem? that django will not now start? if so please provide a few relevant lines from the django logs.

Comment: When I edit my template code, I need to restart redis and server again to see the results. Normally, it must be showed when I refresh the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django development server broken pipe error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253288/django-development-server-broken-pipe-error)