# Getting "Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 33187)" when doing a get request using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to submit a form asynchronously using a `form` tag, `<input type='submit' method=get>`, and *jQuery*.

***When I click the submit button I am getting the following error in my terminal traceback:***

`[24/Mar/2016 03:55:14] "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 200 1270
[24/Mar/2016 03:55:14] "GET /submitted/1458791714827 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 33187)`

***Here is my HTML...***

```
<body>
    <h1>API: Disney</h1>
    <form method="get">
      <input type='submit' value='CLICK ME VIEW ALL TIMESTAMPS BETWEEN NOW AND 5 MINUTES AGO!'></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

***Here is my jQuery...***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var submittime = new Date().getTime()
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submitted/' + submittime,
        });
    });
})
```

***Here is my View...***

```
class SubmitValue(View):
    def get(self, request, currdate):
        val = random.randrange(1,100)
        date = int(currdate)
        Data.objects.create(value=val, curr_time=date)
        return redirect('/')
```

***Here is my apps urls.py file...***

```
url(r'^submitted/(?P<currdate>\d+)$', SubmitValue.as_view()),
```

***Here is my Models...***

```
from django.db import models

class Data(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    curr_time = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253288/django-development-server-broken-pipe-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `input type=submit` is clicked, because I put `method="get'` in the `form` tag, it is sending an unnecessary get request that runs simultaneous to the `$.ajax` get request. This causes the `broken pipe` error. To get rid of it, I just pulled the `method='get'` out of the `form` tag so when the user clicks the `input type=submit` it send only one get request.

***Like this!***

```
<body>
    <h1>API: Disney</h1>
    <form>
        <input type='submit' value='CLICK ME VIEW ALL TIMESTAMPS BETWEEN NOW AND 5 MINUTES AGO!'></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably you could/should handle the click event of the submit button and inside use the prevent